# Django RestframeWork Serializer relations , How to get the data of both of One to One Models?

Tags: python, django

The mode is:

```
class Userinfo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='用户信息'
        verbose_name_plural='用户信息'
    user=models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='userinfo',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='用户'
    )
    location=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='地点（勾选宏达,否则福年）')
```

And the Restframework Token class:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Token(models.Model):
    """
    The default authorization token model.
    """
    key = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_token',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User")
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)
```

My serializers is:

```
class UserinfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Userinfo
        fields="__all__"

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        exclude=('password',)
    userinfo=UserinfoSerializer()

class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Token
        fields = '__all__'
        depth=3
    user = UserSerializer()
```

I want to Response the data of User and the One to One Model Userinfo,but I just get the user. what can I to?

Here is my current result of Token serializer data,and The userinfo is null, How can I get the userinfo data?

```
{
    "key": "2012964fb4ffe07dc58c33a64d0ce48bedd34643",
    "user": {
        "id": 3,
        "userinfo": null,
        "last_login": null,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "username": "333",
        "first_name": "叶同学",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "is_staff": false,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2017-12-08T16:39:00+08:00",
        "groups": [],
        "user_permissions": []
    },
    "created": "2017-12-14T10:40:58.933072+08:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in class meta of UserSerializer

```
depth = 1
```

OR

use UserinfoSerializer for 
userinfo = UserinfoSerializer(source="userinfo")

like

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userinfo = UserinfoSerializer(source="userinfo")
    class Meta:
        depth = 2
        model=User
        **fields = ('userinfo')** # You missed this that's why you used depth but it was not working for you. Please replicate same in TokenSerializer
```

#### Please see below my edit

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model=Token
        fields = ('__all__','user')
        depth=3
```

May be instead of all, you need to mention fields which are required.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain clearly.  Token is one to one with User, and User is also One to One with Userinfo, when I serializer Token class ,I want to get both User and Userinfo,User is easy to get ,Because Token class has an attribute user ,when serializer Token , it will get User data with userid. But Userinfo will not work,Because Userinfo is not Directly related to Token .  Usually,When we query Userinfo which has One to One with User ,We just like this: user.userinfo. but I have no idea to get User.userinfo data when serializer.

Comment: Please check I just added line, dept = 2 But you need to add this to Token Serializer

Comment: fields = ('__all__','userinfo') This statement was important when you add, so basically you have to add that in all serializers.

Comment: I overwrite the function `def to_representation(self,instance):` of `serializers.ModelSerializer`，and so I can add the infomation that I want.

Comment: Ok, this is also good work around but in REST framework we can achieve such things using RAW input and custom processing, and one method that applied is also good.